# Facebook graph API response is slow

Tags: facebook

I am using following graph API to fetch post information from Facebook:
https://graph.facebook.com/skyrainforestrescue/posts
but it loks that response of this API is slow. It takes 2 seconds to get the response.

Where as I am also using following API to fetch Youtube information;
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists
which is very fast in response.

So fetching information from facebook using the above said api is slow, can you please let me know why this serveice is slow and is there any other service which could bring fast response to get this post and any other information from facebook.

Regards,
Anoop

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is there any other way by which we can get a speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with the Facebook graph API and thus could not block page generation on the response. We decided to load the information async and provide the user with the information as soon as it's available.